# Gatling Simulation setup for a custom scenarios

Tags: scala, gatling

I am quite new to the Gatling environment.

What can be the simulation setup for the below scenario?

- 10 Users need to hit an API for 2 mins.
- After 2 mins the Users need to be increased uniformly to 20.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below piece of code-

```
setUp(
    <scenarionName>.inject(
      constantConcurrentUsers(10) during(120)
      ,rampConcurrentUsers(10)to(20) during(<duration>))
  )).protocols(httpProtocol)
```